# Python3 (Anaconda3) and Matplotlib plots specified x-ases values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

My question is about a readability issue with a plot. I read several similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them solved completely the problem.

I have a txt file with 100 abscissa and ordinate values. 
I want to plot them but on the x-axes, I want to be shown only specified tick values.
E.g: the 1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,44th,88th, and the 99th point. It is only something that I want for better readability because I want to plot all the points anyway.
What I tried is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.xlabel("Values")
plt.ylabel("Percentage")

for i in range(99):
    try:
        filename = "Folder_Name/foo_%d.txt" % i
        filevals = np.loadtxt(filename, usecols=1) 
        idx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 44, 88, 99]
        y = [filevals[k]*100 for k in idx]
        plt.plot(range(len(idx)), y, 'o-', label="values_foo_%s" % i)
        plt.xticks(range(len(idx)), idx)
    except IOError or IndexError:
        break

plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("plot_test.pdf")
plt.close()
```

As a result, of course, the graph obtained plots only that values ignoring the other points and, as a consequence, the distance between the 5th and the 44th points is the same as it is between the 4th and the 5th.

Comment: `plt.xticks(idx)` imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write: `plt.xtick([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 43, 87, 98])`

Also, don't forget that a list index begins with 0.